# Converting radio button selections to data

Tags: java, data-binding

In my Java "restaurant menu" GUI application for my class we have to allow users to select their food from a menu then order it. Right now you can select from a few different foods on radio buttons. I was wondering if there's a standard way to translate what's on the radio button (ie "Milk") to some sort of data (in this case price, such as 2.5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would seem better to me to assign a product id to the radio buttons, and then in your controller invoke your backend to fetch the product(price).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a if statement..
like if(selected item==milk)
       int cost= 2.;

and then you can use these cost variable as rqrd..